# Does Caddy server serves Django static and media files?

Tags: django, caddy

No. 4 of [this](https://caddy.community/t/caddy-and-django/2781) says

> Take care of your statics and medias

Normally I takes care them by `Nginx` in dev-server or `S3/CloudFront` in prod-server. But this time I judge `Caddy` is a webserver like `Nginx`. Then I read on the [DockerFile](https://github.com/caddyserver/examples/blob/master/django/Caddyfile). But I couldn't find any example of them

**Question:**
My understanding is when I use `Caddy` I have to use something else to serve `statics and medias`.
Am I correct?
If not please show the reference then I will study further

Answer (score 4):

According to [caddy website](https://caddyserver.com/features) it is able to serve static files. You can tell Caddy to serve static files by using `except` keyword:

```
    domain.tld {
        root /var/www/project/folder
        proxy / localhost:8000 {
            transparent
            except /static
        }
    }
```

Assuming that your static files are stored under `/var/www/project/folder/static`, any url that begins with `domain.tld/static/` should be served by Caddy server as static file.

Comment: By that `except /media` should do the same thing?

Comment: @Sarit Yes `except /media` should do the same thing.

Comment: What if I have caddy serving 2 instances of the same application. For example, I have static assets under `staging-static` and `prod-static` but in both cases the url for it is `/static/`. How does one root from url static to path/to/static?

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Caddy doesn't support `except` directive.

You can serve static files like this:

```
    domain.tld {
        root /var/www/project/folder

        handle {
          reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
        }

        handle /static/* {
          file_server
        }
        handle /media/* {
          file_server
        }
    }
```